# How to programatically fire input event using raw javascript?

Tags: javascript

I can't find a solution for this in anywhere. Can someone help me ?

```
<input type="text" id="myText" oninput="alert(this.value);"><br><br>
<div onclick="document.getElementById('myText').value='123';NowCauseTheEvent,Plz !">
   change
</div>
```

Basically I need to know how to programatically raise the event input after I change the value programatically as well. (something to place on the "NowCauseTheEvent,Plz" after the document.getElementById('myText').value='123'

ty !

BTW, this is not about custom event, but native event and I will REALLY appreciate to stop to vote for close this one because THIS IS NOT A CUSTOM EVENT !!!!

Comment: Please explain better what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Any reason you are running javascript inline rather than in a function? Also can you try explain what you want the client to do and what you want the webpage to do, I'm finding it hard to understand your question...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger event in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

Comment: Nope. it's not a duplicated. That thing is for custom event. And this is not a custom event. It's a native event., Justinas.

Comment: @NewToJs, I cannot use a function. Long story ! Starts with : I need to send raw html to a 3rd party library.

Comment: He want's the `oninput` event to fire on his `<input>` when the div's `onclick` inserts `123` into the `<input>`. You could try setting the `onclick` of the `<input>` and then calling `document.getElementById("myText").click()` in the `<div>`.

Comment: Well you need to give more information other than **"Something"** - *"something to place on the "NowCauseTheEvent,Plz""*

Comment: If you read the code , you will understand, NewToJs

Comment: I can't  jdgregson ...must be very very very mandatory on the input event - the 3rd party library requires it.

Comment: @MarcoS.Junior it works in my answer below, but I removed it as calling `oninput` is a similar but far better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work across browsers and trigger the event you require.

```
<div onclick="document.getElementById('myText').value='123';document.getElementById('myText').oninput()">
    change
</div>
```

Use the following in your placeholder:

```
document.getElementById('myText').oninput()
```

Comment: No worries, glad it helped.

Comment: Great answer Ausxor, just beat me to it :p +1 for that!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on Firefox and Chrome but fails on IE11.

```
<input type="text" id="myText" oninput="alert(this.value);"><br><br>
<div onclick="document.getElementById('myText').value='123'; document.getElementById('myText').dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));">
       change
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome !! That's exactly what I need ! I just need to find a way to make this work in IE...I will try to find a new one to make it work and Ie and then I send you back to edit and you got my "answered"